# How to select all records from one table that do not exist in another table but return NULL in the record that do not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have an issue. i have two tables in my database, tableA and tableB. tableB contains data from tableA because tableB is foreign key from primary key from tableA but not vice versa. how can i select all records from tableB that not contains in tableA AS NULL records?

```
tableA field : field1, field2, field3
tableB field : field1, field2, field3, field4, ...
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that was it

```
CREATE TABLE #input_a (id INT)
CREATE TABLE #input_b (id INT)

INSERT INTO #input_a VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #input_a VALUES(2)
INSERT INTO #input_a VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO #input_a VALUES(4)

INSERT INTO #input_b VALUES(1)
INSERT INTO #input_b VALUES(5)
INSERT INTO #input_b VALUES(3)
INSERT INTO #input_b VALUES(6)


SELECT b.id, a.id FROM #input_b as b LEFT JOIN #input_a as a ON b.id=a.id
DROP TABLE #input_a
DROP TABLE #input_b
```

Check it out :
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f447b6ff6f986d4bdfcda66a2be1b4c5

Comment: I' m glad that I could help, have a nice day :)  @FannyKaunang

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following:

```
Select 
  * 
From
  TableB
LEFT JOIN
  TableB
  ON TableA.primary_key = TableB.foreign_key;
```